# Boot devices disabled in BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I cannot boot from a USB stick as all boot devices are disabled (shown in parentheses) in the BIOS.

I cannot find an answer in searches on the topic, and would be most grateful for a solution.

Comment: Many new UEFI systems have Secure Boot on (may be "Windows" or "Other"). You may need that off. And you also may have separate settings to allow boot from USB or USB full support. If you allow USB boot then that is not considered Secure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things here.
1st try F12 when starting up - this typically goes directly into boot mode.
If that doesn't work...
2nd try this method - granted it's for a DVD player, but this may help you enable the Legacy Bios Mode or the UEFI (CSM) Compatibility Support Module which should help realize the USB drive.
https://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-uefi-bios-options-how-to-boot-from-dvd
If that doesn't work....
3rd try this method - remove the USB device get into BIOS settings and try the above (2nd method) then reboot with USB device installed so that it may recognize the USB drive.
If that doesn't work...
4th try this method - When in the BIOS area his "CTRL + F1" this should give you all options available.
If that doesn't work...
5th try this method - Open up your computer (be very careful not to short anything use a grounding strap) and find your CMOS Jumper and reset your BIOS - this will be specifically called out in your motherboard's manufacturer's manual for clarification.
Hope this helps.